# How can I learn Random Matrix theory as a first year undergraduate student?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-matrices

I have finished Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra twice and Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and also I have finished MIT OCW 6.041 Probability Course,I am very interested in Random Matrix Theory,I think that might be good for Deep Learning and Machine Learning, so I want to ask question How can I learn Random Matrix theory and is my mathematical background sufficient to understand RMT, also I know Calculus 1-2-3 and Differential Equations.

Thanks for responses.

Comment: How strong is your background in multivariate Statistics/probability distributions?

Comment: what is your suggest,how can I improve my background in multivariate statistics distributions?

Comment: If you don't know too much about multivariate statistics, I would start there. You can begin by understanding how the normal distribution extends into a multivariate space, as well as how hypothesis testing works there. Some background on principal component analysis may also result useful. For the later jump onto Random Matrix Theory, there I cannot help you that much

Comment: Write some simulations that sample some random Hermitian matrices and find their eigenvalues. See if you can start to see the semicircular law for some moderately big dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Okan, lisansin ilk yilinda random matrix theory ogrenmek istemen vizyon sahibi oldugunu gösteriyor ;) Hangi okuldansin?

Leaving this aside, this would be my response:

- First, I'd say that the probability you'll need for random matrix theory (RMT) would require fair amount of concentration inequalities. Be sure to have completely mastered those (starting from basic Markov-Chebyshev bound to Chernoff, Azuma, McDiarmid type inequalities). While they may not be directly applicable, the way to develop these inequalities is quite universal.
- Do read stuff such as variational characterization of eigenvalues (e.g. Courant-Fischer minimax principle). For this type of linear algebra background, you'd need slightly more than Axler and Strang. One good book is Matrix Analysis by Horn and  Johnson.
- You need a bit more advanced stuff, again on probability line. For instance, standard courses does not cover very much stuff on Gaussians. The stuff including how to handle Gaussian (and in general exponential tails), Gaussian integration by parts, maximum of Gaussian, all revolve around similar themes, but you need to learn them.
- You can start reading notes of Roman Vershynin here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3027 Funnily, as I write this, I do have the note in front of me now, to be used in my research.

Comment: I am from Izmır Institute of  Technology ,I have been studying on Machine Learning and Deep Learning ,I think these subjects are important and they seems like they don't contain math but  I know that Artificial Intelligence is almost Math, and I strongly believe that the future will be dominated by Quantum Computing and Artificial Intelligence, I read the article about applications of RMT , and I infered that RMT might be important to change the future,my aim is to change the future.

Comment: Both machine learning and deep learning are, in fact, using actually quite a bit amount of math (of course, I mean theoretical works). It is still a mystery why, say, local algorithms such as gradient descent converge to give 0 training error, despite the loss surface being highly non-convex, and complicated. People try to explain this in series of papers, under some (natural or non-natural) assumptions. The tools they use is precisely concentration inequalities, local analysis of optimization algorithms, and RMT.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to build up as many mathematical background as you can, especially since you are a first year in undergrad. Neural nets have started becoming very popular in very recent past, and there is a chance by the time you get to grad  school, the popular vibe will be something else. (For instance, in early 90's this was $H_\infty$ control, early 00's, random matrices and concentration inequalities all of a sudden started becoming quite popular). In all these fields, the successful guys are often those with a strong math background.

Comment: Siz hangi okuldansınız hocam?

Comment: Bogazici'ni bitirdim Huseyin, doktora yapıyorum ABD'de. Sansin ve yolun açık olsun calismalarinda!

Comment: Finally,do you have any textbook or any material or anything suggestion for strenghtening my math background.

Comment: Depends on which fields you want to work on. Assuming you want applied math, here is a list:
1) Probability: Start learning more advanced stuff, if you have mastered 6.041. Williams has a book Probability and Martingales, which is perfect to start with. Lecture notes by Amir Dembo (at Stanford), and the book by Rick Durrett (this is quite advanced, and you need real analysis/measure theory for it).
2) Optimization Theory: For linear, read Bertsimas Tsitsiklis. For Convex, read books of Bertsekas (you can find these books on library genesis, don't ever pay for a book at all).

Comment: For optimization, also notes by Yurii Nesterov are good.

3) Real Analysis: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, especially first 7 chapters. When I self-studied this book, it took me a very long time, but I tried to solve as many of the end-of-chapter problems as I can. Extremely important.

4) Matrices: If you want to start from basics, and need encyclopedic reference, start by Theory of Matrices, Gantmacher. If you need more advanced, then Matrix Analysis by Horn & Johnson is a gem.

5) Learn some discrete probability as well. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/mdp/index.html

Comment: Let me know if you need more specific questions.

Comment: Teşekkür ederim hocam,cevabınız için.

Comment: Ne demek, kolay gelsin Okan.

Comment: What is suggestions for textbooks that don't have answer key?How can I be confident in my answer ?